# MySQL Connection Error for TDV

Tags: mysql, connectivity

I am trying to connect to a MySQL database using Tibco Data Virtualization Studio (TDV).

I was able to connect to the database using MySQLWorkbench. I checked my.cnf and skip-networking is not present.

TDV is throwing the following error:

```
    "xx.xx.xx.xx:3306@" with the supplied connection information.  [datasrc-3961050]
Unable to connect to data source "/shared/Admin Database/Data Sources/CACHE DATABASE/MySQL Cache" at
    "jdbc:mysql://xx.xx.xx.xx:3306/DBNAME".  Make sure the URL information, user name and password
    are correct.  [datasrc-3961025]
Cause: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server. [Log ID: 85a492e6-04c4-491a-be42-d9b29eb93472
```

Any ideas how I can correct this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We connected with Tibco support to resolve this issue.

Steps:

1. Change jar from mysql-connector-java-8.0.11.jar to mysql-connector-java-5.1.48.jar. Place the jar file "mysql-connector-java-5.1.48.jar" in location 
   "\conf\adapters\system\mysql_5_5". Then restart the TDV server.
2. Create a new MySql 5.5 datasource with same credentials. Open the advanced settings panel for the new datasource. Then change the connection format to "mysql://xx.xx.xx.xx:3306/DBName?useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true"

Connection is successful.